# regular expression conditional to extract domain name of email address

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

I want to extract the domain name of an email address but only the part before the domain.

```
@([\w]+)
```

with an email address like "john@telenet.be", I can extract telenet. However, when the email address is "john@invoice.telenet.be" I get "invoice" instead of "telenet".

I tried with a condition, but I can't get it working.

Comment: try this one: `@(.+)\.` here is the example: https://regex101.com/r/v3v896/1

Comment: Unless you have a list of valid TLDs then your task is futile. Think about this, how would you handle `john@invoice.telenet.co.uk`?

Comment: Anyways, `[^.@]+(?=\.[^.]+$)` would work for your specific example. https://regex101.com/r/FLd4nj/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [rfc522](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322), which defines the format of a valid email address, the *local part* of an email address, i.e. the part that precedes *@domain_name*, can contain a '@' character if it is within a *quoted string*. So you want to be sure that you start scanning following the *final* '@'.

The following regex is specific and will scan into capture group 1 the next to last level of the domain name:

```
[@.]([^.@]+)\.([^.@]+)$
```

1. `[@.]` - Matches either a '@' or a '.'. This matches the start of a new domain level. The rest of the regex will guarantee that there are no '@' characters in the remaining characters to be scanned.
2. `([^.@]+)` - Scans in to capture group 1 one or more characters that are either '.' nor '@'.
3. `.` - Matches a '.'.
4. `([^.@]+)` - Matches one or more characters that are either '.' nor '@'.
5. `$` - Matches the end of string.

[See Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X3zFmh/1).

A second approach uses a simpler regex to first scan whatever follows the final '@' to capture the full domain:

```
(?<=@)[^@]+$
```

1. `(?<=@)` - A Positive lookbehind assertion stating that the preceding character is a '@'.
2. `[^@]+` - Matches 1 or more non-'@' characters.
3. `$` - Matches the end of the string.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Q3X6f/1)

If your regex engine does not support lookbehind assertions, then use instead the following regex in which case the domain will be in capture group 1:

```
@([^@]+)$
```

Then you can split the scanned domain on the `.` character and select any *N* parts of the domain as follows (the code is Python):

```py
import re

email = "john@invoice.telenet.be"

m = re.search(r'@([^@]+)$', email)
if m:
    # We have a match
    domain = m.group(0)
    domain_parts = domain.split('.')
    # the penultimate part: 'telnet'
    print(domain_parts[-2])
    # the last 2 parts: telnet.be
    print('.'.join(domain_parts[-2:]))
```

Prints:

```
telenet
telenet.be
```

[See Python demo](https://ideone.com/0oyQZ9)

Comment: thanks for the extended explanation!! very helpfull! :)